# Flutter using bloc in showDialog not working

Tags: flutter, dart, dialog, bloc, flutter-cubit

I am using `Bloc` and want to access a `cubit` within a `showDialog`-Widget.

I read that I have to pass the correct `context`, since `showDialog` creates its own.

I tried it like this:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocProvider(
      create: (context) => CouponCodeCubit(
        onSuccess: onSuccess,
        request: request,
      ),
      child: Builder(
        builder: (cubitContext) {
          return Center(
            child: UISecondaryButton(
              title: UILocalization.parentsAddChildDetailsButtonCoupon(),
              onTap: () {

                showDialog(
                  context: cubitContext,
                  builder: (_) {
                    return StatefulBuilder(
                      builder: (_, setState) {
                        return _Dialog(
                          cubitContext: cubitContext,
                          initialValue: initialValue ?? '',
                          focusNode: foucsNode,
                          onRemoveCoupon: onRemoveCoupon,
                        );
                      },
                    );
                  },
                );
              },
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

But when I call `final couponCodeCubit = widget.cubitContext.watch<CouponCodeCubit>();` inside my `_Dialog` it fails with:

> Exception has occurred. ProviderNotFoundException (Error: Could not find the correct Provider<CouponCodeCubit> above this Builder
> Widget
>
> This happens because you used a `BuildContext` that does not include
> the provider of your choice. There are a few common scenarios:
>
> - You added a new provider in your `main.dart` and performed a hot-reload.   To fix, perform a hot-restart.
> - The provider you are trying to read is in a different route.
>
> ...

I even tried wrapping it with a `StatefulBuilder` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67433171/flutter-cant-find-bloc-in-the-parent-tree-when-using-showdialog).

But nothing is working. I also tried passing the Cubit, but this won't update `_Dialog` when state changes.

What am I misisng here? How can I solve this? Let me know if you need any more info.